# Can't sum Angular 4 numbers

Tags: angular, sum

I'm learning Angular4 and I'm trying to make a simple sum, but when doing the calculation, it concatenates the numbers and does not add them up. Does anyone know what is the correct way to perform this exercise?

```
<h2 class="nombre">suma: {{ suma() }}</h2>

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  nombre: string;
  numero1: number;
  numero2: number;
  numero3: number;
  constructor() {
    this.numero1 = 0;
    this.numero2 = 0;
  }
  suma (): number {
    this.numero3 = (this.numero1 + this.numero2);
    return  this.numero3;
  }
}
```

Comment: As written in your post, this should work imo. Maybe you can give more details so that we understand better what's wrong?

Comment: Is there any other place where the varialbes `numero1` or `numero2` are used? If yes, could you add those pieces of code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to cast the numbers type from `string` to  `number`

```
<h2 class="nombre">suma: {{ suma() }}</h2>

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  nombre: string;
  numero1: number;
  numero2: number;
  numero3: number;
  constructor() {
    this.numero1 = 0;
    this.numero2 = 0;
  }
  suma (): number {
    this.numero3 = (Number(this.numero1) + Number(this.numero2));
    return  this.numero3;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a "cast" and should not be the way that kind of issue is addressed.

Comment: "Cast" is convert from one type to other... In MDN `Number` page you can find..
**"In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion."** 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number, in the OP post i cant see if he manipulates the variables in other context, so with the available information my suggestion was do a cast.

Comment: A cast is a type conversion, a type conversion is not necessarily a cast.

Comment: A square is always a rectangle but that doesn't mean that a rectangle is always a square. Similarly, a cast is always a type conversion but that doesn't mean that a type conversion is always a cast.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat haha i understand your comment (would be nice to point some references)!! _NicolasBoulet-Lavoie_ deleted his reply, so my above comment is not more useful anymore.

Comment: Oh ok, I though it was directed to me and that there was an error of @

Comment: It's pretty hard to find a reference that says exactly that though. The idea is that a **cast** is the action to change the type of a variable (`(` `)` in java, `<` `>` in typescript) whereas the type conversion done in your example is creating a new variable with a different type from the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide full code of file so i am guessing that is problem. Your code works perfectly fine in my component. 
Here is working example https://angular-f3szpb.stackblitz.io
The great way to start learning Angular is [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions here.

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION. OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ numero3 }}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';

  numero1 = 1;
  numero2 = 4;
  numero3 = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.numero3 = (this.numero1 + this.numero2);
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You should define the value of the variables numero1, numero2 and numero3 at the declaration without the type ([TSLint will give you an error otherwise](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-inferrable-types/)). I'm doing the summation in the ngOnInit since Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties. (see [Angular Component Lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)).

I've made a Plunker to shows you a working example ([see src/app.ts](https://plnkr.co/edit/UDFeoOMFaRKMda3bWvy7?p=info)).

Finally, you should not call a function from the template, you'll lose the execution context (`this`).

Answer (score -1):

Actual type of numero1 (or numero2) is string. You need to parse it to number type first.

Comment: What do you mean their actual type is string? They are declared as `number` and initialized with `= 0`. I hardly see how they could be `string`.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat I encountered it before. Despite the fact that they declared as number and initializaed properly *in the moment* when suma() called these fields may be set with any other type. Unfortunately Typescript in angular allowing it. I meant that. After all if values concatenates it says that type actually is string. No other options here. I cannot understand why you downvote my answer.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine. But I think it's the wrong way at looking at the problem anyway and that the place that forces the assignation with a string should be fixed instead of the method doing the sum.